# Difference between quoted vs unquoted keys in switch() in R?

Tags: r

In some simple tests I constructed, quoted and unquoted keys in calls to `switch()` appear to behave the same way.

E.g.

```
value <- "cat"

switch(value,
  cat = { "cat" },
  dog = { "dog" },
  mouse = { "mouse" },
  "unknown"
)
# [1] "cat"

switch(value,
       "cat" = { "cat" },
       "dog" = { "dog" },
       "mouse" = { "mouse" },
       "unknown"
)
# [1] "cat"
```

Above we see both `cat` and `"cat"` cause the correct code block to be executed.

#### Question

Is there any time where quoted vs unquoted keys matter, and if so which of unquoted or quoted is best practice - I am interested in writing robust code and not have to deal with strange anomalies months later, so even subtle quirks matter here.

Comment: If it's a legal name (not a reserved word, no spaces, special characters, doesn't start with a number, etc), then you do not need to quote it. If it is, then you need to quote it.

Comment: @r2evans does this mean there's no disadvantage to quoting, but a possible disadvantage (ambiguity) when not quoting, therefore quoting is the safer option?

Comment: I tend to quote all if I have to quote any, just for consistency and readability. There is no difference in execution. I don't believe profiling will show any difference, either. If in doubt, I believe quoting is always safe.